# Handling Checkbox values in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a check box inside a form in my MVC view like below :

```
<div class="row" style="width: 98%;">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 22%;">Active</div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 23%;">
    <input type="checkbox" ID="chb_Active" style="color: #428bca;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 22%;">Inactive</div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 23%;">
    <input type="checkbox" ID="chb_Inactive" style="color: #428bca;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 20%;"></div>                          
</div>
```

On my controller the ActionResult method looks like below.

```
public ActionResult MethodName(string submit, FormCollection collection) 
{
  bool chb_Active = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["chb_Active"]);
  bool chb_Inactive = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["chb_Inactive"]);
  //Some other operations
  //The return view
}
```

This is how I handled all my other controls(like dropdownlist) which works fine and gets the selected values.

The problem arises with checkboxes values, they are always set to False even thou I checked or unchecked them they always return a False.

I'm new to MVC please help or point me to the right direction. I have tried without the FormCollection and form still no positive results.

Most of the archives relating to this are not helpful in this situation as their checkboxes have values in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

Firstly, your HTML inputs need a `name` attribute - not just an `id` - because it is the name which is used as the key in the form collection.

Secondly, they need a value. This is trickier, and is an age-old problem with checkboxes. By default, a browser will submit the value associated with a checkbox if it is checked, and will not submit anything if it is unchecked. Therefore, in order to make a checkbox submit `true` when checked and `false` when not checked, you need to do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ID="chb_Active" name="chb_Active" value="true" style="color: #428bca;">
<input type="hidden" name="chb_Active" value="false">
```

(and similarly for your other checkbox, if you want to have two of them).

Using this setup, `false` will be posted back as the value of the `chb_Active` property of the form if the checkbox is not checked. If it *is* checked, then both `false` and `true` will be posted back, and ASP.NET will automatically pick out `true` for you if you use its model-binding feature, like so:

```
public ActionResult MethodName(string submit, bool chb_Active) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked...Sorry for not accepting the answer in time. Was out of the office.

Answer (score 4):

Form inputs are not picked up on the `id` attribute but the `name` attribute.

Changing your inputs to read:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chb_Active" ...
```

will allow the data to be posted back to the controller. You also should add a `value` attribute and a hidden input as per [Ben Griffiths' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911789/1185053).

---

#### A better way to do this

The more MVC-y way to do this is to use View Models.

Create a folder `/ViewModels/ControllerName` and put a class in that (it doesn't actually have to be in this folder, but it's nice to follow the convention followed by views):

```
public class MethodNameViewModel
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
}
```

In view you can now do

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.ControllerName.MethodNameViewModel

<div class="row" style="width: 98%;">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 22%;">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Active)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 23%;">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Active, new { style = "color: #428bca" })
    </div>

    @* Same for other field *@
```

Then your post action becomes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(MethodNameViewModel methodNameViewModel) 
{
    var active = methodNameViewModel.Active;
    var inactive = methodNameViewModel.Inactive

    // ... etc
 }
```

Comment: I think your inserted edit under *A better way to do this* is a good answer, but the original answer, before this, is misleading. Simply adding name attributes to the OP's original code wouldn't solve the problem, and you haven't explained why

Comment: @BenGriffiths Ah, having just read your answer I see your point. I'll add reference to your answer in mine :)